# How garbage collection determine time of garbage objects to collect and how long object is pushed from young generation to old generation?

Tags: garbage-collection

To optimize for this scenario, memory is managed in generations (memory pools holding objects of different ages). Garbage collection occurs in each generation when the generation fills up. The vast majority of objects are allocated in a pool dedicated to young objects (the young generation), and most objects die there.
How GC define time for objects which not use from any objects into running program? How GC determine to move objects from young generation to old generation?

Comment: First, the garbage collector usually runs, when there is not enough free memory to serve an actual allocation request. Some garbage collectors also allow to configure a threshold for the memory in use, to trigger a collection. In either case, it’s not the amount of garbage (unused objects) that triggers anything, as that amount is not known before the garbage collector run. The promotion from young to old is typically implemented by a simple counter. After an object survived a configurable number of collections, it gets promoted to the old generation.

Comment: Hi Holger, I think GC running in background and iterate objects to push to old generation or young generation. If objects not reachable, memory pool will track and notify for GC, object will be deleted when GC not collect during copy memory. But how long unreachable objects were keep before remove it. e.g: we define 10 nano seconds, then collect. But if after 10 nano seconds, program collect objects again, object become reachable, so how GC resolve this problem?

Comment: You have a fundamentally wrong understanding of garbage collection. First of all, an unreachable object can never become reachable again, that’s the whole point of being *unreachable*. There is is no way for the application to reach it, hence, the application can not change its state. Second, the garbage collection *is* the process of determining which objects are still reachable (and conversely, which are unreachable). No one tells the garbage collector about unreachable objects, as no one knows before the garbage collector ran. Once identified, there is no reason to keep unreachable objects.

Comment: Thanks Holger. I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Holger, I read the Mark and Sweep algorithm, it mention the way GC working to detect objects in unreachable and the way reclaim heap space used to make space available again. In case my application is hangout because of GC running, do we have any solution to kill GC without restart JVM?

Comment: A common situation of gc taking too much time, is when the memory is almost full, but the garbage collector finds a bit reclaimable memory, to fulfill the current allocation request instead of failing, but very soon have to search again for reclaimable memory. Newer gc algorithms allow to configure the operation to fail just like with no available memory, when it takes too much time. The [HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html) might help.

Comment: There is no way to 'kill' the GC. If you are using CMS then the long pauses you are seeing are due to the heap becoming excessively fragmented and the collector deciding that a full compaction of the old gen. needs to be performed.  The time this takes will be proportional to the size of the heap and so can take a long time. G1 is a better solution because of the way that it divides the heap space into regions that can be processed more efficiently. To really eliminate this problem you need a fully concurrent collector like C4 in Zing from Azul (who I work for).

Comment: Thanks Speakjava, I'm using G1, so the system hangout because the try to copy from survivor to survivor or because another reason?

Comment: use the concurrent collector to reduce pause times and use the parallel collector to increase overall throughput on multiprocessor hardware. Does pause times make application hangout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the young generation like a stack.  Objects are allocated at the current stack pointer and the pointer is moved by the size of the object that has been allocated (this is really quick).

When the pointer reaches the top of the Eden space memory range a minor GC needs to occur.  To track all live objects, the collector will start by creating a root set. This is a list of all the objects directly accessible from your program.  The collector does this by scanning the registers and the program stack looking for object references.  Each of these objects will be marked as live and then scanned for object references that they contain for the variables you define in them.  This happens recursively until all objects that can be accessed from your code are marked.

Once this is complete, any live objects in the Eden space are copied to the empty (to) survivor space.  Also at this time, any objects that are still live in the occupied (from) survivor space will be copied into the to survivor space, unless they have reached the tenuring threshold, in which case they are promoted (copied) into the old generation.

To answer your question more specifically, the time an object spends in the young generation will depend on several factors because of the algorithm explained above.

1. How big the Eden space is (the bigger it is the longer it will take to fill up)
2. How fast you are instantiating new objects (the faster you do this, the faster the Eden space will fill up).
3. The tenuring threshold.  This is how many times an object will be copied between the survivor spaces before being promoted to the old generation.
4. The size of the survivor spaces will also play a part as objects will be promoted more quickly if these fill up

Collection of the old generation can use one of several different algorithms but determining which objects are still live uses the same approach as for the young generation, i.e. create a root set and then scan recursively all object references.

Comment: Thank Speakjava so much.

Comment: As a minor point on StackOverflow etiquette, if you appreciate an answer you can click on the up arrow next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to know exactly what kind of answer you're looking for here. But the short answer is that objects get moved when the allocation space they're in gets full.

The young generation allocation space is typically fairly small and typically fills up quickly -- once per second or so, depending on the type of application. Since the vast majority of objects have very short lifetimes, the runtime simply looks for the few objects that are still reachable and moves them to a survivor space. Then the entire young generation space is wiped clean and allocation begins again.

Typically there are two survivor spaces, and when one gets full, the objects in it get moved to the other. After being moved a couple of times, the object gets moved to a tenured object heap instead, which is typically managed with a different kind of GC algorithm (usually a mark-sweep process of some kind).

If an object is not reachable by running code, it effectively doesn't exist anymore. Don't think of the garbage collector as searching to find objects that are no longer reachable and deleting them -- instead, **the right mental model is that the garbage collector continuously keeps objects that *are* still reachable from dying**. If the garbage collector stops paying attention to an object, it will go away on its own: the memory will get reused for some other purpose.

You would probably enjoy Raymond Chen's series of blog posts starting with [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203) and [When does an object become available for garbage collection?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100810-00/?p=13193)

Comment: Hi Daniel Pryden, Thank for your answer. My question relate to JVM. Just one to understand how long does it take for an unused object existing in young generation. while copy memory, these objects will be die or move to old generate. How long memory pool keep objects and remove it to recovery free memory?

Comment: "the right mental model is that the garbage collector continuously keeps objects that are still reachable from dying". If object not use by an another objects, GC will have an algorithm to make it unreachable. How many times or how long object will be tracked as unreachable? e.g: I have two objects A and B, each object contain 10GB data on memory, A is static and running through program, and B is running into a function. After execute the function, B will be not use any more and A still used on another module. How GC keep A and mark B as an unreachable object.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of what I said. If you can't reach the object through any reference read by any code path, it is unreachable. The GC doesn't *make* things unreachable, they *are* unreachable as soon as they cannot be reached anymore. The GC is the "other half" of the allocator, so it can reuse memory by allocating a new object in the same place. So it doesn't need to find all the objects that can't be used anymore, it just needs to ensure that new objects don't get allocated on top of objects that still could be used.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Pryden.

Comment: Hi Danial Pryden, when big objects on my application not release because re-run issues, I see GC running and write logs to servers. So what is difference when GC running to recovery memory and GC running in background to manage objects? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that last comment. If the GC is doing a lot of work, it's usually because the allocator is having a hard time finding where to put new objects. You might need to increase your maximum heap size, adjust the relative size of the young generation, or tune the GC initiation limit or collection strategy. The right configuration depends on your specific application. I would recommend searching Stack Overflow, since there are a lot of existing questions about tuning the Java heap and GC settings.

Comment: My application store 200GB on memory, when the batch run completed, we push all data to memory and user can query data quickly. In case we have a re-run for many countries, the data on first run sometime not removed from memory. So GC running and my application hangout. I tried to tuning memory and test on UAT but UAT are not facing this issue. So I need find the way to fix this issue on PROD.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will search on StackOverflow to fix this issue. Thanks Daniel Pryden